# Elastic Search | How to get original search query with corresponding match value

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm using ElasticSearch as search engine for a human resource database.

The user submits a competence (f.ex 'disruption'), and ElasticSearch returns all users ordered by best match.

I have configured the field 'competences' to use synonyms, so 'innovation' would match 'disruption'.

I want to show the user (who is performing the search) how a particular search result matched the search query. For this I use the `explain` api ([reference](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-explain.html))

The query works as expected and returns an `_explanation` to each `hit`.
Details (simplified a bit) for a particular hit could look like the following:

```
{
   description: "weight(Synonym(skills:innovation skills:disruption)),
   value: 3.0988
}
```

**Problem:** I cannot see what the original search term was in the `_explanation`. (As illustrated in example above: I can see that *some* search query matched with 'innovation' or 'disruption', I need to know what the skill the users searched for)

**Question:** Is there any way to solve this issue (example: parse a custom 'description' with info about the search query tag to the `_explanation`)?

**Expected Result:**

```
{
   description: "weight(Synonym(skills:innovation skills:disruption)),
   value: 3.0988
   customDescription: 'innovation'
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can put the original query in the `_name` field?

Like explained in https://qbox.io/blog/elasticsearch-named-queries:

```
GET /_search
{
    "query": {
        "query_string" : {
            "default_field" : "skills",
            "query" : "disruption",
            "_name": "disruption"
        }
    }
}
```

You can then find the proginal query in the `matched queries` section in the return object:

```
{
  "_index": "testindex",
  "_type": "employee",
  "_id": "2",
  "_score": 0.19178301,
  "_source": {
    "skills": "disruption"
  },
  "matched_queries": [
    "disruption"
  ]
}
```

Add the `explain` to the solution and i think it would work fine...?